# how to maintain msg.sender when internal function call

Tags: solidity

i want to make multiple transfer
this is my code

```
function transferMulti(address[] _to, uint[] _value) public returns(bool success) {
    require(_to.length == _value.length, "require _to[] size == _value[] size");

    for(uint8 i=0; i<_to.length; i++) {
      transfer(_to[i], _value[i]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

but Actually, it was like Mint, Not Transfer...
how to maintain msg.sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way
it use delegatecall
The important point is that you only need to write the data type of the parameter.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    ...
}

function transferMulti(address[] _to, uint256[] _value) public returns (bool success) {

    require(_to.length == _value.length, "_to.length == _value.length");

    for(uint i=0; i<_to.length; i++) {
        address(this).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)", _to[i], _value[i]));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard ERC20 contracts the `transfer()` function can only be called by the account that owns the tokens. If you want to put a contract in the middle, the caller (`msg.sender`) of the `transfer()` function will become the contract, rather than the account that owns the tokens.

If the tokens are owned by an external account not a contract, they will have to either first transfer the tokens to the contract or call `approve()` to give the contract permission to move them with `transferFrom()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `transfer` function (by `transfer` I mean `transfer`, not `transferMulti`) as `public` rather than as `external`.

When `public` function is called from within contract where it is declared, `msg.sender` is preserved, but for `external` functions it is overridden.  See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) for more details.

BTW, I see two major issues in your code:
1. you use `uint8` for counter, thus you will get infinite loop in case `_to.lengeth >= 256`, and
2. You ignore value returned by `transfer` method.